# varnish and apache on separate servers

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

I would like to know if it is possible to install and configure apache on one server and varnish on another server so that we can alleviate the load on the apache server. If it is possible can someone please tell me how to configure it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common configuration to have and is configured through the `host` variable in the backend directive:

```
backend default {
    .host = "1.2.3.4";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

Where `1.2.3.4` is the IP of your Apache-Server.

For more information see [Advanced Backend configuration](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/tutorial/advanced_backend_servers.html) in the Varnish manual.